# Magento 2.3.x Checkout problem Safari browser - blank page

Tags: magento2, checkout

we are facing a strange behavior using **Magento 2.3.x** (now 2.3.3 but also with Magento 2.3.1 the same error occured.

Problem is, that clients using **SAFARI browser** get a blank page during checkout. Footer and header remain normal but checkout page gets blank.

Something seems not to work properly. Safari here not in private mode. All other browser seem to work fine and without problem.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens possibly, or where to look for the bug?

Thanks in advance and Regards.

Comment: Can you please check your var/log/exception.log file ?

Comment: try with Enable Sign Static Files Setting.

Comment: Hello, we have tried multiple options. We are going for a One Page Checkout solution via an extension now, as we could not figure out the problem. Thank you all for your help.